# How to find MS-Word with Windows10 search functionality

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, search-indexing

> **Update**
>   After trying most suggested things (except contacting Microsoft :D) I gave up, and at some point - months later - it suddenly started working but I could not figure out what caused it to work again - so now even if someone posted the right answer, I can't verify it, because I can't reproduce the error any longer...

I'd like to find MS-Word in my Win10-search normally but it doesn't work.
This is how I want it - it is working with MS-Excel:
[image: Excel_win]

When I try the same thing with Word - fail:
[image: Word_fail]

This is my current workaround that I hate, a friend told me about it.
[image: Word_workaround]

I'm guessing it has something to do with indexing, but I have no idea what I should do exactly to make this work.

> EDIT
>   It is in the start menu list under the correct name it seems:
>   [image: Word in start menu]
>
> Also "Microsoft Word" doesn't help:
>   [image: MS Word fail]

Comment: what's the name of MS Word in your locale?

Comment: @phuclv what is "locale"?

Comment: Like, the name of your country: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn965675(v=vs.85).aspx . To find yours, go to [Start] Settings | Time & Language | Region & language .

Comment: I mean if MS Word's name isn't Word in your language (like Wort) then you can't use it to search for Word. Winword is the name of the exe file so it always word. Moreover it also depends on the frequency that you search/use that name. Like if you use Notepad++ more than Notepad or sticky notes then searching for note will show Notepad++ on top

Comment: Do you actually have the Word item in the Start Menu? Can you find it manually in the list? How is it called exactly?

Comment: _phuclv_, I set Google to Deutsch then searched for Microsoft Office; the product name in German is, indeed, Microsoft Word.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the name of Word in my list of...different things in the startmenu and it seems to be "Word" I do not know where else to look for it's "German Name" ;) None of the suggestions are working so far :(

Comment: @K7AAY I added a screenshot "Microsoft Word" is also not working

Answer (score 2):

It works great for me on a Swedish computer with Windows 10 Pro, so either it's a issue on Windows in your language (looks like german to me) or you have a local problem with your computer.

Have you tried to enter a space after you typed Word, i.e. "Word "?

[image: Swedish Windows 10 Pro]

Comment: Yes, I've tried "Word " - same result as when I type "Word" (as seen in my question), and I know there's some kind of problem - but I'm looking for its solution here :D

Comment: My question is only related to my own computer, it works wonderfully on all other computers I have, just like with Excel

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the search index? Search for "index" in Search...

Comment: Another thing that migth work is to try Search and Indexing Troubleshooting: Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Troubleshooting -> System and Security -> Search and Indexing

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: actually after trying many things I gave up, and at some point - months later - it suddenly started working but I could not figure out what caused it to work again. :(

Answer (score 0):

Search on the term *winw* and you will find it.

If that solution is not acceptable, please contact [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hub/4338813/windows-help?os=windows-10) directly.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "microsoft" is even longer to type than "winword", that doesn't solve my problem in this case...and I just tried it - and it actually doesn't work like this on my computer.

Comment: I'm not trying to find any way that works, I'm trying to find a clean way to make it work by specifically typing 'word'

Comment: Please consult Microsoft Windows 10 support at the link above. Since I do not have Deutsch Windows, I could only get so far myself with Windows 10 Support.